# Postgres merge silently ignore unique constraint violation

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, unique-constraint, sql-merge

The following quote is from here: https://pganalyze.com/blog/5mins-postgres-15-merge-vs-insert-on-conflict

> The comment that he essentially made is that the downside of MERGE's
> handling of concurrency is that when you concurrently INSERT, so at
> the same time as you're executing the MERGE statement, there is
> another INSERT going on, then MERGE might not notice that. MERGE would
> go into its INSERT logic, and then it would get a unique violation.
>
> I recall that, back when he initially designed the INSERT ON CONFLICT
> feature, that because of this constraint of how MVCC works in
> Postgres, you cannot implement MERGE with its general syntax and
> options to work in the same reliable way. If you want the generality
> of MERGE, you have to accept the fact that you might get unique
> constraint violations, when there are concurrent inserts, versus with
> INSERT ON CONFLICT, the way it's designed with its speculative
> insertions, guarantees that you either get an INSERT or an UPDATE and
> that is true even if there are concurrent inserts. You might want to
> choose INSERT ON CONFLICT if you need the guarantee.

Pretend then that we're doing a really huge `merge` that will take a long time, and in the process of the merge, there happens this concurrent insert described in the quote above that causes unique constraint violation during the insert logic. What exactly happens in this case? Does it lead to the whole `merge` query failing and throwing a unique constraint exception?

Or, perhaps, if the unique constraint violation does occur for a row or rows in the final insert logic, only those rows that have the unique constraint violation are just silently ignored, and the rest of the insert proceeds as normal?

I would reckon that postgres' `merge` functionality doesn't support this (the latter - silently ignoring unique constraint violations), but I do think this would be a valuable addition to the `merge` functionality, because there will definitely be users (me currently) who wouldn't want their entire merge insert (or update) to fail just because one or a couple of rows had a unique constraint violation.

Comment: What happend when you ran a test?

Comment: I haven't (but if nobody answers me, then I probably will eventually)

Comment: The docs spell it out [MERGE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html): *If the repeated action is an INSERT, this will cause a uniqueness violation, while a repeated UPDATE or DELETE will cause a cardinality violation; the latter behavior is required by the SQL standard.*

Comment: @AdrianKlaver that's of course something I read very careful, which is why I wrote "I would reckon that...". But I would like a definitive answer, and I would like to start conversation on introducing the feature that would allow for silently ignoring instead of tanking the whole query.

Comment: The Postgres developers make  a point of sticking to the SQL standard as much as possible, so I doubt you will get far with this proposal.

Comment: Postgres differs over and over again from the SQL standard, so much so that you're comment itself is pointless. We'll find out if they want to change it or not

Comment: Use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`, then no constraint violation will happen.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm pretty sure ```INSERT ... ON CONFLICT``` would not work here for batch inserts. I'll have to verify with the `INSERT` spec to confirm.

Comment: It will work, unless you cause a deadlock.

Comment: So then even if `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` did work, it wouldn't be any better, I don't think, because by the time then the `INSERT` batch query is done, those same rows that would have caused the unique violation exception on the `merge` query would then cause the deadlock on the `INSERT` query. Perhaps there's some way to avoid it with setting the transaction serializable isolation, I would have to examine that further... but I think the `merge` semantics would be better. Just conceptually, `merge` tries after the select query, `insert` before its over, so the former would seem to be better.

Comment: Yeah, the ```INSERT ... ON CONFLICT``` is a non-starter because of the possibility of causing deadlocks. Deadlocks could be avoided by using strict locking, but then that would lock all of the rows and/or entire table, which is also a non-starter.

Answer (score 0):

I did run some tests using the following code, and I discovered, as expected, that if a unique violation exception occurs during the insert of the `merge` command, this unique violation exception bubbles up and tanks the whole `merge` query.

That means, for example, if you're doing a long running batch `merge` operation, the `merge` might perform 99% of the work, but then if even the last insert row causes a unique violation exception, the whole `merge` query gets rolled back and all the work lost with it.

In many foreseeable uses cases for `merge` I would expect this to be very disappointing and far less than ideal. In my opinion, it would be much better for `merge` to offer the ability to simply ignore the rows that cause unique violation exceptions instead of tanking the whole query.

I am of the opinion that this additional functionality (to ignore rows the cause unique violation exception during the insert query) should be added to both the sql standard and to postgres.

**Code used for testing**

In one sql process run the following:

```sql
create table tmp_table (col int);

insert into tmp_table (col)
select *
from generate_series(1, 10000000) as s(i);

CREATE TABLE tmp_table2 (col int unique);

merge into tmp_table2 tt2
using (
  select *
  from tmp_table
) as tt1
on tt2.col = tt1.col
when matched then do nothing
when not matched then
  insert (col)
  values (tt1.col);
```

In a second sql process, run the following immediately after running the `merge` command in the first sql process:

```sql
insert into tmp_table2 (col)
values (9000000);
```